# Error running npm install --save gh-pages

Tags: reactjs

I am using linux on virtualbox. I tried running the 'npm install --save gh-pages' on the terminal but I keep getting these warnings.

```
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.4
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /react-scripts/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.4
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /webpack-dev-server/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.4
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none was installed
```

Therefore, I cannot 'npm run deploy' successfully. 
What could be the issue and how do I resolve it?

Comment: `WARN` are just warning messages. I also get the same with `fsevents`, must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install gh-pages in Dev dependencies using
`npm install gh-pages --save-dev`
Then create a file something.js and write `var ghpages = require('gh-pages');
ghpages.publish(dir, callback);`

read more about it on [click to read more](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages)